# Request Whitelisting for Java 7 Deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, java, google-app-engine, whitelist

I just took over a project last month.When I tried to deploy the project, it popped up a message told me to migrate to Java 8 application or add to whitelist.
I have tried the steps on the document of migrating to Java 8, but the project couldn't compile well after the migrating.
After that, I enabled the billing of the account, and filled in the Request Whitelisting for Java 7 Deployment.
I have not received the reply since last week.
I would like to know, does the method Request Whitelisting for Java 7 Deployment still work?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

These kind of requests will take up to 1 month, if you have a support package please open a support case in the [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases), Otherwise it is necessary open a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), this is in order to know the status of your request.

Another alternative is to create a Docker container with your application and use App Engine Flexible Environment with a custom runtime (Docker image)

In this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) you can find more information about custom runtimes